# Android Databinding: bind RadioGroup's selected RadioButton index in included layout file to MutableLiveData<Integer>

Tags: android, android-layout, android-databinding

I have a layout file defining a `RadioGroup` containing nine `RadioButton`s. This layout file is included in a fragment layout multiple times.

**For each include of the `RadioGroup` layout, I would like to somehow bind the index of the selected `RadioButton` to a different `MutableLiveData<Integer>` variable in the fragment's `ViewModel`**, each representing a user-chosen score on mutliple nine point scales.

Databinding is setup correctly and works for other parts (e.g. binding click handlers and view visibility to a `MutableLiveData<Boolean>`).

What I tried to do so far is pass my `ViewModel` variable and/or distinct `MutableLiveData<Integer>` variables to the included layout via

```
...
<data>
    <variable name="viewModel" type="my.package.MyViewModel"/>
    <variable name="someVariable" type="androidx.lifecycle.LiveData&lt;Integer&gt;"/>
</data>
...
<include layout="@layout/radiobuttons"
    app:viewModel="@{viewModel}"
    app:someVariable="@{someVariable}"/>
```

and using the same variable declarations inside the `RadioGroup` layout to be able to use them in there. I then tried binding to the `RadioGroup`'s `android:onItemSelected` attribute using

```
android:onItemSelected="@{(parent, view, position, id) -> someVariable.setValue(position)}"
```

resulting in the databinding error: "Cannot find the setter for attribute 'android:onItemSelected' with parameter type lambda on android.widget.RadioGroup"

or adding the following to the `RadioButton`s

```
android:onClick="@{(view) -> viewModel.updateRadioButtonSelection(someVariable, /*INDEX HERE e.g.*/ 0)}"
```

but that gives the databinding error "cannot find method updateRadioButtonSelection(java.lang.Integer, int) in class my.package.MyViewModel", meaning that the `MutableLiveData<Integer>` isn't passed on as such, but it's contained type (I have a method `public void updateRadioButtonSelection(MutableLiveData<Integer> variable, int value)` in the ViewModel class).

Can I specify - in the layout - a binding of which `RadioButton` was selected to an int variable without some detour involving extra code and translating `RadioButton` ids to an index? A one-way binding would suffice - changing the ViewModel variables from code is not intended.

Answer (score 2):

It's `onCheckedChanged`, not `onItemSelected`.

I don't think you need to send the variable to xml if you already have your `ViewModel` and the variable defined there. Just call the respective methods to update the value.

Dummy ViewModel content:

```
  private final ObservableInt firstInflateOptionSelected = new ObservableInt();
  private final ObservableInt secondInflateOptionSelected = new ObservableInt();
  ....
  ..
  .

  public void setFirstInflateOptionSelected(int value) {
    this.firstInflateOptionSelected.set(value);
  }

  public void setSecondInflateOptionSelected(int value) {
    this.secondInflateOptionSelected.set(value);
  }
```

Now in xml, do like this in `RadioGroup`:

```
android:onCheckedChanged="@{(group, checkedId) -> viewModel.setFirstInflateOptionSelected(checkedId)}"
```

Also, the `checkedId` is the View id, not the position. If you want the position. You can convert the view Id as the child position for the `RadioGroup`.

```
android:onCheckedChanged="@{(group, checkedId) -> viewModel.setFirstInflateOptionSelected(group.indexOfChild(group.findViewById(checkedId)))}"
```

Comment: Thanks, but how can I set different method calls for different includes with that? Because I can't put the `android:onCheckedChanged` attribute on the include-tag ("Cannot find setter for attribute...") and putting it directly in that layout makes it the same for each include. Also, since I reuse the `RadioGroup` layout quite often and thus already need many int variables in the `ViewModel`, I was hoping I could avoid having to also write a method for each variable. Would be happy to hear about further ideas.

Comment: If you want to track the selected option, you must have to define a variable either in xml or java. Data-binding doesn’t affect if the layout is reused with no data-binding. You can create public observableInt variable in ViewModel and set it to the layout with ‘BR.setVariable’ method, no need to create setter method. It would automatically update if changed.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand completely. Do your propose looping through every instance of the included layout and setting the onCheckedChanged by hand? The part I'm struggling with is that every time I <include/> my `RadioGroup` layout, I want to bind to a different `ObservableInt` (all present in my single `ViewModel`), ideally directly from within the layout file they're included in. I don't know how to differentiate between the different include sites (hence my idea of passing the `ObservableInt` to the included layout) without going through the outer layout and hooking everything up by hand.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to accomplish what I wanted. Though I'm not too happy with it, I will accept it if nothing else turns up.

Deˣ's answer was very helpful, the only part I didn't know how to do was bind different includes of the same layout to different `ViewModel` variables / methods. I added setter methods for my `MutableLiveData<Integer>` variables representing indices of chosen radio buttons in the `ViewModel` and declared the following variable in the layout to be included multiple times:

```
<data>
    <variable
        name="variableSetter"
        type="java.util.function.Consumer&lt;Integer&gt;" />
</data>
```

This allows me to specifiy a different setter method to be called (via

```
android:onCheckedChanged="@{(group, checkedId) -> variableSetter.accept(group.indexOfChild(group.findViewById(checkedId)))}"
```

) for every include like so:

```
<include layout="@layout/..."
    app:method="@{viewModel::setQuestion1}" />
```